# What systems are based on the following paper?

Tags: machine-learning, large-data, supervised-learning, statistical-learning, multicore

http://papers.nips.cc/paper/3150-map-reduce-for-machine-learning-on-multicore.pdf

This paper has Andrew Ng as one of the authors.

I really liked the idea presented in this paper, and when I looked around, I expected to see some implementation or application of the idea. After all, the idea can be applied to both multi-core and multi-node (multiple computers) systems as well.

My question is, what subsequent research work or machine learning systems were built on top of this? (Is that due to deficiencies in the MapReduce model?) I am interested in large-scale/distributed machine learning systems.

Here is the abstract of the paper:

We are at the beginning of the multicore era. Computers will have increasingly many cores (processors), but there is still no good programming framework for these architectures, and thus no simple and unified way for machine learning to take advantage of the potential speed up. In this paper, we develop a broadly applicable parallel programming method, one that is easily applied to many different learning algorithms. Our work is in distinct contrast to the tradition in machine learning of designing (often ingenious) ways to speed up a single algorithm at a time. Specifically, we show that algorithms that fit the Statistical Query model can be written in a certain “summation form,” which allows them to be easily parallelized on multicore computers. We adapt Google’s map-reduce [7] paradigm to demonstrate this parallel speed up technique on a variety of learning algorithms including locally weighted linear regression (LWLR), k-means, logistic regression (LR), naive Bayes (NB), SVM, ICA, PCA, gaussian discriminant analysis (GDA), EM, and backpropagation (NN). Our experimental results show basically linear speedup with an increasing number of processors.

Comment: Please add whatever context is necessary to understand & answer your question to the post. People aren't going to want to download & read something just to answer your question for you.

Comment: What sort of application are you looking for? The fourth item on Google Scholar's [list of papers citations](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=7784975056176979771&as_sdt=20005&sciodt=1,9&hl=en) for this paper—a list of 980 items, by the by—is the paper introducing [Apache Spark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Spark).

Comment: The Spark paper actually doesn't borrow any ideas from this paper. Quoting it, "For example, a recent paper on MapReduce for machine learning on multicore systems [10] implemented ten learning algorithms without supporting parallel reduction." I am editing the question to add more details.

Comment: Appreciate the edit, but you may have more luck getting an answer if you explicitly define which ideas you're interested in. Again, the paper has 980 citations, so the related works are quite broad. As to the quote, it concludes a paragraph describing Spark as not supporting parallel reduction; that is, it's citing a commonality with the work in Ng.

Comment: Edited to reflect that I am interested in large-scale distributed systems. Spark has a more generalised abstraction (DAGs) compared to the paper above (MR).

Comment: Finally found the answer I was looking for - https://mahout.apache.org/general/faq.html#historical